# how to guess random values from user in pl sql

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

could someone help?

```
declare 
ran int:=dbms_random.value(1,5);
num number;
begin
dbms_output.put_line('enter the num');
num:=&num;

if num<ran then
&dbms_output.put_line('Your num is less'||ran);
elsif num>ran then
&dbms_output.put_line('Your num is greater'||ran);
else 
&dbms_output.put_line('Equal'||num||'='||ran);
end if;
while num=ran loop
&dbms_output.put_line('enter the num');
num:=&num;
end loop;
end;
```

there is some problems ?
what is wrong?
how to guess random numbers what's wrong

Comment: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: inputs 5 times then this problem

Comment: Yes there are problems with this. For one thing, PL/SQL is not interactive. First the client application will interpret the substitution variables (how and whether it does this will depend on the client), then the resulting block will be sent to the server. It can't stop halfway through to ask you stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to prompt for the number separately, and then use the value in a PL/SQL block once you have it.

Substitution variables are a [SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_three.htm) feature and not part of the core PL/SQL language (which is not interactive), so the following works in SQL*Plus. Client applications such as PL/SQL Developer emulate it to varying degrees, so it may also work in those (for example in PL/SQL Developer you would run it in a Command window, or in TOAD you'd use the 'Run as script' option). You may also be able to do something in [Apex](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-and-12c-1968249.html) or using a third party scripting language such as Perl, Python, PowerShell etc.

```
accept mynumber number format 0 prompt "Enter a number between 1 and 5: "

declare
    ran int := dbms_random.value(1, 5);
begin
    if &mynumber < ran then
        dbms_output.put_line('&mynumber is less than ' || ran);
    elsif &mynumber > ran then
        dbms_output.put_line('&mynumber is greater than ' || ran);
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('&mynumber = ' || ran);
    end if;
end;
/
```

I'm not sure what the loop in your example is supposed to do. If you want it to prompt for input repeatedly in a loop you will need to write something in a separate scripting language or another development framework.